# How to add sound in video with .hevc extention without changing its extension

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I use this code to encode a .hevc video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "scale=650:-1" -c:v libx264  -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 1500k -strict experimental -shortest -x264-params lossless=0  -movflags faststart -tag:v hvc1 -g 50000 -q 22  out.hevc
```

But It got only video and no sound at all.I tried to re-encode it to add sound but if only when I change its extension to .mp4 then I can add sound.
How can i add sound and keep .hevc extension?

Answer (score 2):

> How to add sound in video with `.hevc` extention without changing its extension

You can't: `.hevc` is raw HEVC video only.

Comment: Can you tell my why .hevc only had raw video?
I tried to google but can't find the answer
thank you

Comment: FFmpeg is trying to guess the output format by extension of the output unless you hint it with the `-f` parameter and hevc is associated with raw video track, that's why audio was omitted. Why do you need hevc extension anyway? Mp4 container is perfectly suitable and player-compatible when your goal is to encode a video in hevc video format. If for some reason you don't care what the actual container is, you need the audio as well and it is just the hevc extension you're after, you can always force it by using for example `-f mp4 out.hevc`.

Comment: @RobertJohn Using `-f mp4 out.hevc` would still be a MP4 file but with a `.hevc` extension. I doubt that's what you want.